# Database design for word searches in files

Tags: mysql, search, database-design

I want to do single word searches in multiple video caption files. The database will be pre-populated, with the words and in which caption files they appear (probably only 4 or more letter words). I came up with this design, but not sure if there are better options:

[database design for word searches in caption files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znwog.png)

- Maybe dividing the words table in several with the starting letter or the 2 first letters? Or adding the indexing the word too?
- The main bottleneck I can see are the queries in the captions_words table which will be the largest. Probably millions of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Have a `FULLTEXT` index on the column that contains the entire caption.  Then use `WHERE MATCH(...) AGAINST(...)` to search.